# Why are former citizens stuck on Main Street?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Three citizens that moved out of my town a while back appear to be stuck on Main Street.  Would there be a reason why this is happening?

All three of them have been there for about 3 months now. I talk to them everyday and they say they are there to visit, shop, etc. But they never actually leave. No matter what hour of the day I go to Main Street, they are there wandering outside the shops.

I've had former citizens visit in the past and they always seem to leave once the day is over.

Comment: I don't know the cause, but I've seen this happen to my friend too, so it definitely isn't a unique problem.

Comment: This is just part of the game. I think it is random as the same thing has happened to me. It might just choose a few villagers to stay there while others come and go.

Answer (score 1):

They come and go in a cycle, after 16 moves, the oldest villager will leave main street. The villagers that moved out are kept in memory until the game can't keep track of any more. When that happens, the game deletes one of the villagers from its memory. It forgets that villager used to live there and you can get that villager to move back in, though the villager will not remember you. Therefore, the game lost track of all the villagers on main street except those three. I am telling you this from both the animal crossing wikia and my own experience.